# Why does my push() method keep inserting an element of 'undefined' into my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does my push() method keep inserting an element of 'undefined' into my array as the first element every time?

```
var elements;
//Create a namespace.
var dataStructures = {
//Create a class called myStack which is a property of the dataStructures (object).
myStack: function () {

    var topOfmyStack;

    //Add the push method to the myStack object
    this.push = function (element) {
        //If no value was entered then stay at zero index and insert nothing
        if (typeof (elements) === 'undefined') {
           elements = [];
            topOfmyStack = 0;
        }
        //Get the next empty space in the stack
        topOfmyStack++;
        //Place the new value in that empty space
        elements[topOfmyStack] = element;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are resetting your top of stack with `topOfmyStack = 0;` if an undefined element is given and do you even initialize `topOfmyStack` somewhere?

Comment: As @StefanFalk said and also that even after you reset the stack you still insert the `undefined` object. You need `return` from within the `if-clause` or add and `else-clause`.

Comment: Detail: Why don't you just do `elements.push(element);` instead of `elements[topOfmyStack] = element;`?

Comment: why are you doing a `this.push`. That method won't exist on `dataStructures` unless a call to `dataStructures.myStack` is made...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time, you are setting `topOfmyStack` to 0;
The for every call, *including the first one*, you are adding 1 to `topOfmyStack` before adding to the array. So the first time, this becomes 1, not 0.

Setting it to -1 should fix this

```
var elements;
//Create a namespace.
var dataStructures = {
//Create a class called myStack which is a property of the dataStructures (object).
myStack: function () {

    var topOfmyStack;

    //Add the push method to the myStack object
    this.push = function (element) {
        //If no value was entered then stay at zero index and insert nothing
        if (typeof (elements) === 'undefined') {
           elements = [];
            topOfmyStack = -1;
        }
        //Get the next empty space in the stack
        topOfmyStack++;
        //Place the new value in that empty space
        elements[topOfmyStack] = element;
    }
}
```

Or better just push the element onto the array:

```
var elements;
//Create a namespace.
var dataStructures = {
//Create a class called myStack which is a property of the dataStructures (object).
myStack: function () {

    //Add the push method to the myStack object
    this.push = function (element) {
        //If no value was entered then stay at zero index and insert nothing
        if (typeof (elements) === 'undefined') {
           elements = [];
        }

        //Place the new value in that empty space
        elements.push(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
var topOfmyStack;
```

is initially `undefined` You only define it in the below code

```
if (typeof (elements) === 'undefined') {
    elements = [];
    topOfmyStack = 0;
} // here topOfmyStack is still undefined
```

So change the code to

```
var topOfmyStack = 0;
```

so `topOfmyStack++` doesn't go wrong.

Comment: but then this will not add the element to the array, plus it is initialised on the first push as you say, so i dont see a problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Create a namespace.
var dataStructures = {
    myStack: function () {
        var elements = [];
        var topOfMyStack = 0;
    
        //Add the push method to the myStack object
        this.push = function (e) {
            if (typeof (e) !== 'undefined') {
                // Push new value.
                elements[topOfMyStack++] = e;
            }
        };
        
        this.pop = function () {
            if (topOfMyStack > 0) {
                return elements[--topOfMyStack];
            }
        };
        
        return this;
    }
}

var something;
var stack = new dataStructures.myStack();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(something);    // undefined
alert(stack.pop());       // 1
```